# Using Aggregation API Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple task of aggregating some values from database, but the problem is that I need to do it in another `django` application. I need to aggregate Sum of cost, price and average for each month, and display it in a table.

I'm using generic `ListView` so I can aggregate this, so simple example.

in views.py i have:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Sum, Avg

from projects_app.models import Project


class ProjectStatisticsList(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'statistics_app/statistics_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectStatisticsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["price_aux"] = Project.objects.all().aggregate(Sum("price_aux"))
        return context
```

and in template I have:

```
<tr>
   <th class="align-left">{% trans 'Project income' %}</th>
   <th class="align-left">{{ total.price_aux }}</th>
 </tr>
```

My problem is that I'm not getting anything on the template, so I'm wondering if I'm doing the right thing, is there a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template, instead of doing `{{ total.price_aux }}` do:

```
<th class="align-left">{{ price_aux.price_aux__sum }}</th>
```

`price_aux` is the key in the context, and `price_aux__sum` is the dict key from the aggregation query.

Comment: yea, thanks, this was the problem, I wrongly interpreted dict keys